# Virtual functions - architecture question

Tags: c++, object, inheritance

I have :

```
class Game
{
    
};
class Zombie :public Game
{
public:
    virtual int getHP() const=0;
};
class Zombiesmall : public Zombie
{
    int HPy=30;
public:
    int getHP() const;
};
class Zombiebig : public Zombie
{
    int HPz=20;
public:
    int getHP() const;
};

class Player : public Game
{
    int hpk=100;
 public:
    int getHPK() const;   
};

class  Barrel: public Game
{
    
};
```

My lecturer said, that, there is no sense to functions `getHP` and `getHPK` exist at once, so he asked me to change it and he proposed to make one function in `Game` class, so I presumed that he want me to do `virtual` function in class `Game`. I did so, but my question is if there is a sense to do so if I don't need this function in class Barrel at all, but by making virtual function makes me to write the a definition in `Barrel` anyway and I won't ever use it.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too abstract to answer. The class names tells us absolutely nothing about their purpose. My guess is that `K` should inherit from `X` and all of these `getHP()` overrides are not useful (there should be just one `int HP` member in `X` and that class should implement `getHP()`), but I don't know anything about your usecases and why you chose to do it this way in the first place.

Comment: I edited post, sr

Comment: Given the content of your question, you might not even need different classes for zombies and the player. Just have one class that that handles something that has hp and instantiate it with the correct number (e.g. 100 for the player, 20 for a zombie and so on). There is no need to inherit from an empty `Game` class, nor for polymorphic functions. Try to figure out the difference between 'different instances of a type' and 'different types`. (And as a side note, in 99% of the cases, if your class has any virtual function, it should have a virtual destructor.)

Comment: I'd probably go with `Entity` as base class, from which `LivingEntity` inherits and has non-virtual `getHP()` method, and from this class inherit `Player` and `Zombie`. `Barrel` inherits from `Entity` or something like `InanimateEntity` if needed. Of course, that's under assumption that these classes are not empty, bitmask comment is correct - given code we see, players and zombies do not differ from each other.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Nice pun :P

Comment: Random aside - make sure your base type has a virtual destructor. You should look up *why* too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an inheritance tree that should help:

```
Entity (renamed your Game)
  <- Creature (with getHP())
    <- Player (one of the implementations)
    <- Zombie
      <- SmallZombie
      <- BigZombie
  <- Barrel (without getHP())
```

In C++:

```
class Entity { // base for other classes
public:
  virtual ~Entity() = default;
};

class Creature : public Entity { // has getHP()
public:
  virtual int getHP() const = 0;
};

class Player : public Creature { // is-a Creature => must implement getHP()
private:
  int hp = 100;

public:
  int getHP() const override {
    return hp;
  }
};

// similar for zombies

class Barrel : public Entity { // not a Creature => doesn't have getHP()
};
```